# How to accelerating query speed using aggregation in mongoDB when dealing with IoT Data

Tags: mongodb

In the first, English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Having performance issues when running aggregation to get Data in mongodb.

I hava total 60 million records about IoT data in my mongoDB, And the data structure like this。

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f2d845b8a2763468c29ca3b"),
"si" : "sensorId",
"ts" : ISODate("2020-08-07T16:42:02.000Z"),
"tp" : "MOISTURE_CONTENT_DELTA",
"v" : {
    "d" : -0.118
}
```

- Has an compound index on `si` and `ts`

Now I use Aggregation to get example data（720 data points）for chart display.

So my solution is this：

1. Split the total duration to 720 part

[example-pic-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxV7M.jpg)

2. pick the first value in 720 part

[example-pic-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqqKj.jpg)

3. Get the result array

Here is the example code for aggregation

```
    {
      {$match:{ 
            si: { $in: ['sensorId'] }, 
            $or: [{ts: { $gt: new Date(1638288000000), $lt: new Date(1638288300000) } }, 
                { ts: { $gt: new Date(1638291540000), $lt: new Date(1638291840000) } }, 
                { ts: { $gt: new Date(1638295080000), $lt: new Date(1638295380000) } },
                  .....] 
        } 
      },
       {$group: {
        _id: {number: {$toInt: {$divide: [{$toLong: '$ts'}, 7200000]}}, si: '$si'},
        oId: {$first: '$_id'},
        si: {$first: '$si'},
        ts: {$first: '$ts'},
        tp: {$first: '$tp'},
        v: {$first: '$v'}
      }},
     { $project: { _id: '$oId', si: '$si', ts: '$ts', tp: '$tp', v: '$v' } },
     { $sort: { ts: -1 } }
    }
```

It takes about 30 seconds before getting the result.
I have tried to optimize performance，but it's not effective.

Should I continue optimize this aggregation? Or find another solution?

The executionStats are as follows (each '...' means there are 720 numbers of similar data )

```
/* 1 */
{
  "stages" : [
    {
      "$cursor" : {
        "query" : {
          "si" : {
            "$in" : [
              "moisture-content-delta-algorithm-test",
              "WK7",
              "_moisture_content_X",
              "_moisture_content_III"
            ]
          },
          "$or" : [{
            "ts" : {
              "$gt" : ISODate("2021-12-23T01:39:43.591Z"),
              "$lt" : ISODate("2021-12-23T01:44:43.591Z")
            }
          },
            {
              "ts" : {
                "$gt" : ISODate("2021-12-23T01:53:43.591Z"),
                "$lt" : ISODate("2021-12-23T01:58:43.591Z")
              }
            },
            ...
          ]
        },
        "fields" : {
          "si" : 1,
          "tp" : 1,
          "ts" : 1,
          "v" : 1,
          "_id" : 1
        },
        "queryPlanner" : {
          "plannerVersion" : 1,
          "namespace" : "iot-dev.algorithm_data",
          "indexFilterSet" : false,
          "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
              {
                "$or" : [{
                  "$and" : [
                    {
                      "ts" : {
                        "$lt" : ISODate("2021-12-27T18:40:43.591Z")
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "ts" : {
                        "$gt" : ISODate("2021-12-27T18:35:43.591Z")
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                  {
                    "$and" : [
                      {
                        "ts" : {
                          "$lt" : ISODate("2021-12-27T16:06:43.591Z")
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "ts" : {
                          "$gt" : ISODate("2021-12-27T16:01:43.591Z")
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  ...
                ]
              },
              {
                "si" : {
                  "$in" : [
                    "WK7",
                    "_moisture_content_III",
                    "_moisture_content_X",
                    "moisture-content-delta-algorithm-test"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
              "$or" : [
                {
                  "$and" : [
                    {
                      "ts" : {
                        "$lt" : ISODate("2021-12-23T12:14:43.591Z")
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "ts" : {
                        "$gt" : ISODate("2021-12-23T12:09:43.591Z")
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$and" : [
                    {
                      "ts" : {
                        "$lt" : ISODate("2021-12-23T04:18:43.591Z")
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "ts" : {
                        "$gt" : ISODate("2021-12-23T04:13:43.591Z")
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                ...
              ]
            },
            "inputStage" : {
              "stage" : "IXSCAN",
              "keyPattern" : {
                "si" : 1,
                "ts" : -1
              },
              "indexName" : "sensor_short_id_and_timestamp_index",
              "isMultiKey" : false,
              "multiKeyPaths" : {
                "si" : [],
                "ts" : []
              },
              "isUnique" : false,
              "isSparse" : false,
              "isPartial" : false,
              "indexVersion" : 2,
              "direction" : "forward",
              "indexBounds" : {
                "si" : [
                  "[\"WK7\", \"WK7\"]",
                  "[\"_moisture_content_III\", \"_moisture_content_III\"]",
                  "[\"_moisture_content_X\", \"_moisture_content_X\"]",
                  "[\"moisture-content-delta-algorithm-test\", \"moisture-content-delta-algorithm-test\"]"
                ],
                "ts" : [
                  "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
              "stage" : "FETCH",
              "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "OR",
                "inputStages" : [
                  {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                      "si" : 1,
                      "ts" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "sensor_short_id_and_timestamp_index",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                      "si" : [],
                      "ts" : []
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                      "si" : [
                        "[\"WK7\", \"WK7\"]",
                        "[\"_moisture_content_III\", \"_moisture_content_III\"]",
                        "[\"_moisture_content_X\", \"_moisture_content_X\"]",
                        "[\"moisture-content-delta-algorithm-test\", \"moisture-content-delta-algorithm-test\"]"
                      ],
                      "ts" : [
                        "(new Date(1640261683591), new Date(1640261383591))"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                      "si" : 1,
                      "ts" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "sensor_short_id_and_timestamp_index",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                      "si" : [],
                      "ts" : []
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                      "si" : [
                        "[\"WK7\", \"WK7\"]",
                        "[\"_moisture_content_III\", \"_moisture_content_III\"]",
                        "[\"_moisture_content_X\", \"_moisture_content_X\"]",
                        "[\"moisture-content-delta-algorithm-test\", \"moisture-content-delta-algorithm-test\"]"
                      ],
                      "ts" : [
                        "(new Date(1640233123591), new Date(1640232823591))"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  ...
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
          "executionSuccess" : true,
          "nReturned" : 616,
          "executionTimeMillis" : 31199,
          "totalKeysExamined" : 124656,
          "totalDocsExamined" : 124654,
          "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
              "$or" : [
                {
                  "$and" : [
                    {
                      "ts" : {
                        "$lt" : ISODate("2021-12-23T12:14:43.591Z")
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "ts" : {
                        "$gt" : ISODate("2021-12-23T12:09:43.591Z")
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$and" : [
                    {
                      "ts" : {
                        "$lt" : ISODate("2021-12-23T04:18:43.591Z")
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "ts" : {
                        "$gt" : ISODate("2021-12-23T04:13:43.591Z")
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                ...
              ]
            },
            "nReturned" : 616,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 31107,
            "works" : 124656,
            "advanced" : 616,
            "needTime" : 124039,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 1510,
            "restoreState" : 1510,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 124654,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
              "stage" : "IXSCAN",
              "nReturned" : 124654,
              "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 120,
              "works" : 124656,
              "advanced" : 124654,
              "needTime" : 1,
              "needYield" : 0,
              "saveState" : 1510,
              "restoreState" : 1510,
              "isEOF" : 1,
              "invalidates" : 0,
              "keyPattern" : {
                "si" : 1,
                "ts" : -1
              },
              "indexName" : "sensor_short_id_and_timestamp_index",
              "isMultiKey" : false,
              "multiKeyPaths" : {
                "si" : [],
                "ts" : []
              },
              "isUnique" : false,
              "isSparse" : false,
              "isPartial" : false,
              "indexVersion" : 2,
              "direction" : "forward",
              "indexBounds" : {
                "si" : [
                  "[\"WK7\", \"WK7\"]",
                  "[\"_moisture_content_III\", \"_moisture_content_III\"]",
                  "[\"_moisture_content_X\", \"_moisture_content_X\"]",
                  "[\"moisture-content-delta-algorithm-test\", \"moisture-content-delta-algorithm-test\"]"
                ],
                "ts" : [
                  "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                ]
              },
              "keysExamined" : 124656,
              "seeks" : 2,
              "dupsTested" : 0,
              "dupsDropped" : 0,
              "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$group" : {
        "_id" : {
          "number" : {
            "$convert" : {
              "input" : {
                "$divide" : [
                  {
                    "$convert" : {
                      "input" : "$ts",
                      "to" : {
                        "$const" : "long"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "$const" : 840000.0
                  }
                ]
              },
              "to" : {
                "$const" : "int"
              }
            }
          },
          "si" : "$si"
        },
        "oId" : {
          "$first" : "$_id"
        },
        "si" : {
          "$first" : "$si"
        },
        "ts" : {
          "$first" : "$ts"
        },
        "tp" : {
          "$first" : "$tp"
        },
        "v" : {
          "$first" : "$v"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$project" : {
        "_id" : "$oId",
        "si" : "$si",
        "ts" : "$ts",
        "tp" : "$tp",
        "v" : "$v"
      }
    },
    {
      "$sort" : {
        "sortKey" : {
          "ts" : -1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "ok" : 1.0,
  "operationTime" : Timestamp(1640857960, 1),
  "$gleStats" : {
    "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
    "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000010")
  },
  "lastCommittedOpTime" : Timestamp(1640857960, 1),
  "$configServerState" : {
    "opTime" : {
      "ts" : Timestamp(1640857957, 2),
      "t" : NumberLong(3)
    }
  },
  "$clusterTime" : {
    "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1640857960, 1),
    "signature" : {
      "hash" : { "$binary" : "28NxSnlpMZ27avQqsJfY1s6k63Y=", "$type" : "00" },
      "keyId" : NumberLong(7025900497152245761)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can consider indexing on the `si` field also (along with the `ts`, as a compound index). In general, indexes are applied during the `$match` stage, when it appears as the first stage of the aggregation. Compound indexes, allow indexing on multiple fields, as in you case during the `$match` stage. Refer this: [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/)

Comment: sorry for my mistake, I already have a compound index on `si` and `ts`。I have edited  my issue

Comment: You can know more about the query performance and index usage by generating a _query plan_, using the `explain()` (with "executionStats" verbosity/mode). You can generate and include it in your post.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance， I have updated the issue。 I noticed there are too many rejected plans, does it matter?

Comment: It should not matter - the query optimizer has rejected these candidate plans. The [winning plan](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#mongodb-data-explain.queryPlanner.winningPlan) is the one the optimizer selected.